# Canvas.drawText not drawing in exact position

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

This is a gist of what my Android app does:
1. User selects a picture from gallery or from default pictures in app
2. The picture is displayed in an ImageView
3. User clicks anywhere on the picture
4. User types text and clicks 'Done' button
5. Text is drawn on the bitmap using Canvas.drawText

**The Problem:** The text is sometimes not drawn where the user clicks. I noticed that this problem occurs only for those pictures that are bigger than can fit in the ImageView.

This is the code that retrieves the coordinates where the user clicked:

```
mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    xCoord = event.getX();
    yCoord = event.getY();
    mEditText.setText("");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xCoord + ", " + yCoord, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

return true;
}
    });
```

And this is the code that draws the text on the Bitmap:

```
String text = mEditText.getText().toString();

Paint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textPaint.setColor(colorId);
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

Bitmap mutable = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutable);            

canvas.drawText(text, xCoord, yCoord, textPaint);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(mutable);
mBitmap = mutable;

mEditText.setText("");
```

I am using a 720x1280, 320 dpi emulator.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: use ImageView.getImageMatrigettgettwhich returns a Matrix used for image drawing

Comment: @pskink Could you please post an answer with the code showing how I can draw text on the Bitmap using that? Thanks!

Comment: first of all why do you want to draw on Bitmap? draw on View's Canvas

Comment: @pskink Yes, by 'Bitmap' I meant the Bitmap's Canvas, which I am already using in the code shown above.

Comment: no,  no Bitmap's Canvas,  you should draw on View's Canvas

Comment: @pskink Ok, then could you please post an answer with an example showing how I can do this?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html